# Salesforce Marketing Cloud : Fetch Email data via REST vs SOAP

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I am part of an organisation that is building data pipeline for salesforce marketing cloud customers to help analyse their data. One of our customers has recently shifted from using Classic Email to Content Builder Email and we are having data loss issues as SOAP implementation is not fetching the email data anymore. I am aware that Content Builder requires REST Implementation.So my question is :

Is there a way to identify if the user(our customer) is using Classic Email or Content Builder email beforehand, so that we can use appropriate implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no out of the box solution for this.

You could try to have a 'flag' inside your data that would show which is CB and which is classic, like a row in the sendable DE that is collected in Send Log (may not work if your sendable DE goes out to classic and CB emails).

Or you could set an AMPscript var in each email that identifies which builder you used and have that collected in the Send Log.  E.g. create a column in the sendlog named 'Environment' then in each email put in `SET @Environment = "CB"` (or "Classic" on Classic emails). You can then use this field to differentiate your API calls in for SOAP or REST.

Another solution is you could put a flag inside the naming convention on your emails, so that if CB the name would prefix with 'CB_'. You can then utilize the email name to differentiate on your data collection.

If utilizing a flag is not an option, your only other option then is to use a [REST GET with a filter on email objects only](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/assetSimpleQuery.htm) to collect name/id combos of all the CB emails and use REST retrieves on them and then exclude those emails from your SOAP calls. This can be unwieldy and process heavy though.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but i would want to have the required information at the very beginning i.e. at connection level So that i can re reroute my request to REST/SOAP accordingly.

Comment: I understand @ShreshthaGarg - but there is no way to differentiate without a manual flag inserted or retrieving more information prior to running your data pipeline collection. In the next year or so, this issue should become obsolete as classic will be sunsetted and all will be in CB only.

Comment: Thanks ! Got it :)